# Uncaught referenceError: Object is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I have a Javascript object in an external js file that looks like this:

```
function SomeObj() {
    this.property = 0;
    this.property = null;
}

SomeObj.prototype = {
    methodA: function() {},
    methodB: function() {}
}
```

In my View files, I load it like this:

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src="someObj.js"></script>
```

And in jQuery, I instantiate it like this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

var someObject = new SomeObj();

</script>
```

At this point. `console.log` spits out the UncaughtReference error saying `someObj` is not defined.

What's wrong ?
Help me with this
Thanks in advance

Comment: someObj = new someObj() doesn't look good...

Comment: var someObj = new someObj(); looks better^

Comment: actually I am doing var someObj = new someObj() ; sorry, it is a typo on my part

Comment: @ParijatKalia that's the issue, you're reusing the same name

Comment: @ParijatKalia: Problem is not just `var` is that you have two variables with the same exact name.

Comment: If follow JS conventions and start constructors with capital letter  you'll never encounter this problem again.

Comment: As a best practice, capitalize the first letter of any function that will be used as a constructor ( new SomeObj() ).

That code seems to work in the Chrome console, but it may be problematic to have a variable and a function of the same name.

Comment: _"And in my jQuery,"_ - What jQuery is that?

Comment: yeah, none of the above are correct answers, the above is simply skeletal code and not the exact names of the objects and constructors, they are all capitalized now...the problem still persists

Answer (score 4):

That is because of ambiguous naming of `Variable` and `Object`

```
someObj = new someObj();
```

Give it a different name

```
var obj1 = new SomeObj();
```

What happens if you do this

```
var obj = {
   a :a
}
```

**a is not** defined yet so it spits out an error

Comment: actually, the above is simply skeletal code, they both have different names, for instance they are var someObject = new SomeObj() ;. The problem still persists